# How do I do twitter analytics with all the restrictions with the API

Tags: twitter

My boss wants me to do some Twitter Analytics of various Customers using keywords. He wants stats like "xxxx tweets in the past one hour" etc..

Twitter API allows the fetching of 100 tweets per request.

I dont know how to do this sorta analytics. Should I stream tweets in real time and do processing? I dont know what to do.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter is making it more and more difficult to get full data through their API and are using the existing social media monitoring and analytics firms to supply the market with their needs.

You can an existing analytics company such as Radian 6, Netbase, or Brandwatch (to name a few) to give you reports and dashboards to do your analysis.

Also you can use [Gnip](http://gnip.com/) (disclaimer: I work for Gnip) to give you the raw data that the Twitter API would, without any rate limits. The product [Twitter PowerTrack](http://gnip.com/twitter/) is what you would want to use.